# Add custom admin add page/template in Django

Tags: python, django, angularjs, django-admin

In my current Django project I need to implement one admin page that loads some asynchronous data with AngularJS to fill the form fields. Some form fields (on client side) will be updated by AngularJS.

My question is: What's the right approach to add this complex add/change page of my AdminModel? Should I create a pure json / AngularJS client side page?
The forms fields will be the same of my Model field, so I would like to use ModelForm.

I tried with:

```
class ContractAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    add_form_template = "admin/add_contract.html"
```

and then in my contract.html template:

```
{% extends "admin/base_site.html" %}
{% load i18n admin_urls admin_static admin_modify %}

{% block content %}
<form action="" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
   {{ form.as_p }} <!-- this produces nothing -->
<br />
<br />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: I can't find the admin/add_form template (or figure out which template is getting used by default), but looking at other templates in django/contrib/admin/templates/admin, it looks like you need to do adminform.form instead of just form.as_p, but I could be making an incorrect assumption

Comment: Thanks! It works. Now I need to understand what is the right approach to solve my problem. Can I follow this road or I need to add one view/template by overriding get_urls() method of ModelAdmin?